# Android View With ListView Doesn't Grow

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a LinearLayout that I am dynamically populating with a custom View (pseudo code):

```
<LinearLayout>
```

The custom view is simply a LinearLayout like so (pseudo code):

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView>
  <ListView width="match_parent" height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

When the parent displays, it only shows the TextView and first row of the ListView for each custom view.  Is there anything I can do to make the custom view expand to show all items from the ListView?

(It's worth noting, I plan to make each custom view like an accordion...expandable/collapsable)

[image]

Comment: If you want to make if expandable then you should use SimpleExpandableListAdpater.

Comment: I took a look at SimpleExpandableListAdapter but it will require a LOT of work to make the groups appear the way they do in my app, and there is very little documentation around how to implement the SimpleExpandableListAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Android.Animation namespace/package and used ValueAnimator to animate the expand/collapse behavior I was looking for:

```
    ValueAnimator animator = null;
    if (expanded) {
        handle.SetImageResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.ArrowDownFloat);
        animator = ValueAnimator.OfObject (new HeightEvaluator (listView), height, 0);
    } else {
        handle.SetImageResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.ArrowUpFloat);
        animator = ValueAnimator.OfObject (new HeightEvaluator (listView), 0, height);
    }

    animator.SetDuration(500);
    animator.SetInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator (1));
    animator.Start ();

    expanded = !expanded;
```